# Viewing JQuery functions live within a browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

Is there a way to view the executed Jquery on a webpage such as Chrome. I assume this is only covered by an extension.

eg. if a dropdown menu is activated when i hover over a phone icon. Can I see the Jquery code (perhaps in a popup or console)

Comment: All JS code can be viewed in the console. In chrome for example, open the DOM inspector, then click the sources tab, and choose the file in the left side pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for my request I did was.

Right click on element, inspect, then Event Listeners and the pending JQuery event will be listed. Click on JS link to take you straight to the JQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider writing a "console log" in your instructions.

```
/ Event setup using a convenience method
$( "p" ).click(function() {
    console.log( "You clicked a paragraph!" );
});
```

See further here : https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

Comment: Its viewing other sites JQuery elements on the page I am interested in

Answer (score 0):

Chrome provides you the facility to see Javascript and html code in ***developer tool***. Right click on the page and go to ***inspect element*** or use ***F12*** to open developer tool.

If you want to break your javascript execution at any point you can write ***debugger;*** in the code or you can add ***breakpoint*** to the source.

In firefox also you can use the same way. Other than that with firefox you can  also use ***Firebug***, which is a good extension with firefox which helps to ease your job.

Comment: Its viewing other sites JQuery element code on the their webpage I am interested in

Comment: If I am getting you correct, you want to see the script of some other sites which is not built by you. If that is the case you can still see it in the same way or to see complete source code you can use view page source of context menu. Now a days many sites are using bundled and minified version of their script, so in that case it is difficult to see it.